# NextJS + AppCheck -> Token is not part of every request

Tags: javascript, next.js, firebase-app-check

I'm testing Firebase AppCheck on my website. It is currently running on around 15% of Verified requests. (I'm not enforcing it)

Originally I was thinking that number will increase as there is some caching in the browser and I updated to a newer version of JS SDK. But it seems to jump around 15% all the time.

I inspected to HTTP request made by a browser and I found out that SOME of my requests do have "x-firebase-appcheck" header inside of the form Data in a POST.

But ALL of my GET requests or SOME other POST don't have that header at all.

I used it inside of the NextJS project and init AppCheck in _app.tsx component

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const token = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA as string;
    initializeAppCheck(firebaseApp, {
      provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider(token),
      isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true,
    });
  }, []);
```

I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong or if this has something to do with the fact some routes are SSG / SSR?

Create Data method:

```
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

export default async function createData(colllectionName: string, data: PasteModel) {
  let result = null;
  let error = null;

  try {
    const response = await addDoc(collection(db, colllectionName), data);
    result = response.id;
  } catch (e) {
    error = e;
  }

  return { result, error };
}
```

Read Data method

```
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
export async function readDataWithId(collection: string, id: string) {
  let docRef = doc(db, collection, id);

  let result = null;
  let error = null;

  try {
    result = await getDoc(docRef);
  } catch (e) {
    error = e;
  }

  return { result, error };
}
```

How I read data on a route:

```
export async function getStaticProps(p: any) {
  const { result } = await readDataWithId('myCollection', p.params.slug);

  if (!result?.data()) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: `/404`,
        permanent: true,
      },
    };
  }

  const parse = parseToJson(result);
  return {
    props: { paste: parse },
    revalidate: 600,
  };
}
```

Firebase App Check screen:
[image]